# Oracle 12 c database::Is there any other way to drop the column with out uncompression table in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, compression, oracle12c, database-partitioning

We have table which is partitioned ( & sub partitioned), compressed and also have a huge volume of data. While dropping one column(`E_POOL_ID`) from a existing partitioned table with compression enabled then columns is going to unused columns under dba_unused_col_tabs with column name like `SYS_C****`. Due to this unused columns (not visible in the actual table) our exchange partition jobs has been failed.

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production    0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production  0
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production   0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  0


TMP_PART_TEST1------- Partitioned table with compression enabled

TMP_PART_TEST1_STG--- Normal table.This table always truncate and load on monthly basis.


DROP TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1;

CREATE TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1
( POOL_ID NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL,  
  NAME   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  E_POOL_ID NUMBER(15))
PARTITION BY RANGE (POOL_ID)
(  
  PARTITION POOL_ID_1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),  
  PARTITION POOL_ID_2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),    
  PARTITION POOL_ID_3 VALUES LESS THAN (6)
) ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED;

SELECT * FROM TMP_PART_TEST1;
--No rows

DROP TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG;

CREATE TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG
( POOL_ID NUMBER(15)    NOT NULL,  
  NAME   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
  E_POOL_ID NUMBER(15));

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(1,'TEST1',22);

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(2,'TEST2',23);

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(3,'TEST3',24);

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(4,'TEST4',25);

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(5,'TEST5',26);

COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 exchange partition POOL_ID_1 WITH TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG WITHOUT VALIDATION;
--table altered

SELECT * FROM TMP_PART_TEST1;
--5 rows exchanged

Here I am dropping this column E_POOL_ID in both tables.

ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 drop column E_POOL_ID;
--table altered

ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG drop column E_POOL_ID;
--table altered

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(6,'TEST11');

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(7,'TEST12');

INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(8,'TEST13');

COMMIT;

select * from TMP_PART_TEST1_STG;
--3 rows

ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 exchange partition POOL_ID_3 WITH TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

While dropping columns,the partitioned compression table(s) column is going to dba_unused_col_tabs data dictionary.

```
select * from dba_unused_col_tabs where table_name='TMP_PART_TEST1';
```

I found out the solutions, we can uncompress the partitioned table and drop the column and again compression the tables.

But due to the unavailability of space in the server we can't the uncompression the table in oracle database since its huge of amount of data.We have more than 50 years of history records are available in that table.

Is there any other way to drop the column with out uncompression table in oracle database?.

Comment: What Oracle error code are you getting when doing the `ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 exchange partition` command?  `ORA-39726`?  Please edit your question to include the error code.  Would you be able to upgrade to Oracle 12.2?

Comment: I am getting the below error,

Error  in :TMP_PART_TEST1TMP_PART_TEST1_STG column or type mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
ORA-06512: at "TESTDBEX.TMP_PART_TEST1_PKG", line 618
ORA-06512: at "TESTDBEX.TMP_PART_TEST1_PKG", line 791

current version

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: I ran your code (and in my run, fixed a missing comma in your `TMP_PART_TEST1_STG` DDL), and no errors when running your code.  Your error information in your comment shows your PL/SQL code is raising the error; look there.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60673714/edit) your code to include the information in your comment, and include all of the error information.  Looks like you omitted the first `ORA-` error code.  Thanks!

Comment: Drop and recreate both tables.Can you please try the below script.
INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(1,'TEST1',22);
INSERT INTO TMP_PART_TEST1_STG VALUES(2,'TEST2',23);
ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 drop column E_POOL_ID;
ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG drop column E_POOL_ID;
select * from dba_unused_col_tabs where table_name in('TMP_PART_TEST1','TMP_PART_TEST1_STG');
--i can see the entry
ALTER TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1 exchange partition POOL_ID_3 WITH TABLE TMP_PART_TEST1_STG WITHOUT VALIDATION;
ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

Comment: @sivaramanpvi I still can't reproduce your error.  But it would help if you modified your question instead of adding comments.  Try to simplify the question as much as possible - remove all unnecessary columns and rows, and the question is more likely to attract attention.